# jQuery code makes element hide. I can see the element hiding during page load. Any way to make that not happen?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have code like

```
if (windowURL.indexOf('example.com/w/') > -1 ) {                                                                                                   
    $('.wpd-login').css('display', 'none');
});
```

As you can see it relies on jQuery running to know whether or not to display it. There is only 1 page out of 100+ where I want this element hidden.

The problem is that I can see the 'hide' action happening as the page loads.

Is the only workaround for this hiding everything by default and then creating explicit conditions for 99% of the other pages where I do want to show that element? (Since it looks more normal for something to *show* than *hide* during load)

Or is there a solution?

Comment: If you're generating the pages with some server-side language, add some logic to print that element only in the pages where it's needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

I would also recommend using JS not JQuery for this, it will speed up everything.

```js
document.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    //dom is ready, window.onload fires later
    
    document.querySelector("body").style.visibility = "hidden";
    //hidde body
    
    console.log(window.location.href);
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('https://stacksnippets.net/js') > -1) {
      document.querySelector(".wpd-login").style.display = "none";
      //hide element
    };
    
    //show body with slight timeout
    setTimeout(function(){ document.querySelector("body").style.visibility = "visible";  }, 200);
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="wpd-login">
    .wpd-login
  </div>
  <div >
    no .wpd-login
  </div>

</body>
```

Or even try  like this:

```js
document.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    //dom is ready, window.onload fires later
    
    document.querySelector("body").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
    //hidde body

    console.log(window.location.href);
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('https://stacksnippets.net/js') > -1) {
      document.querySelector(".wpd-login").style.display = "none";
      //hide element
    };
  }
};


window.onload = function(e) {
  //document.readyState will be complete, it's one of the requirements for the window.onload event to be fired
  //do stuff for when everything is loaded
  document.querySelector("body").style.visibility = "visible"; 

//if it didnt work, use delay:
//setTimeout(function(){ document.querySelector("body").style.visibility = "visible";  }, 200);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="wpd-login">
    .wpd-login
  </div>
  <div>
    no .wpd-login
  </div>

</body>
```